# Delete an item from a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I wrote this code to delete an item from a linked list. I checked it and it works, but I want to know if the logic could be written simpler or clearer.

```
typedef struct linked_list{
  int value;
  struct linked_list * next;
}linked;

int deleteSpecificItem(linked ** head, int val)
{
 if(!head || !(*head)) return -1;
 linked * tmp = *head;
 int ret;
 linked * listToDel;
 if(tmp->value == val)
 {
    *head = (*head)->next;
    ret = tmp->value;
    free(tmp);
    return ret;
 }
 while(tmp->next != NULL)
 {
    if(tmp->next->value == val)
    {
        listToDel = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = tmp->next->next;
        ret = listToDel->value;
        free(listToDel);
        return ret;
    }
    tmp = tmp->next;
 }
 return -1;
}
```

When checking if a pointer is `NULL`, I can use either `!head` or `head != NULL`. What is preferred in companies?

Comment: Problem: Your code does not compile. You're missing the definition of `linked` (which I suspect ought to be called `node` istead)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apart from the less-than-ideal variable and type names already mentioned you are doubling up on code just to check `head` first and then separately doing the same again for every other node. The only difference is that you need to modify head if the element to be removed is the first one. This can be condensed into a single loop:

```
int deleteSpecificItem(linked** head, int val)
{
    if (!head || !(*head)) return -1;

    linked* tmp = *head;
    linked* prev = NULL;

    while (tmp->value != val && tmp->next != NULL)
    {
        prev = tmp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    if (tmp->value == val)
    {
        if (prev)
        {
            prev->next = tmp->next;
        }
        else
        {
            *head = tmp->next;
        }
        free(tmp);
        return val;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

The way this works is: First we try to find the node which should be removed and we also keep a pointer to the previous node. Once the loop finishes there are several cases to check:

- If the current value is not equal to the one we are looking then it's not in the list and we can return
- If the current value is equal to the one we are looking for then `tmp` points to the node which needs to be removed

  - If we have a valid `prev` then rewire by skipping `tmp`
  - If we don't have a valid `prev` then apparently `head` needs to be moved
  - Now the current node is unlinked and we can delete it
  - We can also return `val` instead of remembering the value of the current node because we know that they are equal.

Regarding `!head` vs `head == NULL`: I tend to prefer `!head` if it's for simple pointer checks and `prev->next == NULL` when the expression is more complex. However some companies enforce the style `NULL == head` because a typo like typing `=` instead of `==` will yield in a compile error this way (you can't assign something to a constant) instead of an accidental assignment. I never managed to consistently do it that way (old habits die hard) and to be honest I've never run into a bug due to this (compilers these days spit out warnings for these kind of constructs).

Answer (score 5):

My concerns are with the type name `linked` and the variable name `listToDel`. `linked` is really a node, not a handle to a linked list. Similarly, `listToDel` is the node that's going to be deleted, not a list that's going to be deleted.

Also, `tmp` is a very poor variable name; it gives no indication about what it's used for.

You also might be able to save some indirection by changing from using `tmp` to using `curNode` and `nextNode`.

Comment: Thank you, I agree and will keep that in mind next time.